# How to create java based custom xml editor adhering to a particular xsd?

Tags: java, xml, swing, xsd

Our project or application is Java awt swing based application. We have a requirement in which I need to introduce a new screen in which user can start typing and create an xml document like a developer would do in ..say eclipse IDE.

The xml document that will be created through this new screen, will adhere to an xsd. So only particular tag and corresponding child elements can be used by the user.

User may need help, like content assist, if he/she forgets a particular xml tag name or available attributes for a xml tag or possible child elements in a xml tag. User may press Ctrl + Space and the autocomplete feature should help show possible list of available options that user may use.

I want to develop such a screen, an xml editor UI in one sense... and have no clue how to start with it.

But i am not sure, if there are any xml libraries already available in market, that we can use in our awt swing based application ?

Any suggestions or advice in this regard will really help.

Answer (score 3):

Google for `JSyntaxPane`. The original project has no commits for the last 4 years, but there are some forks which provide some improvements. In this project you can find syntax highlighting (based on JFlex, so you can create your own syntax) and some other nice features, like line numbers, find/replace dialog, etc. This project has also word completion, but I don't know whether it satisfied your requirements. If not, you'll need to implement the code proposal by yourself.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I did a quick search on google about JSyntax... especially this one: -
[link](https://dzone.com/articles/how-create-editor-java-applica) ... However, the autocompletion feature seems to rely on hardcoding present in the property file... need to investigate more ....